# How to check if UIFont is system font?

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, uikit, uifont

I have the following code for that creates multiple fonts.

```
UIFont* systemFont1 = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
UIFont* systemFont2 = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
UIFont* systemFont3 = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:12.0];

UIFont* customFont1 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:12.0];
UIFont* customFont2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Regular" size:12.0];
UIFont* customFont3 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:12.0];

UIFont* customFont4 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro" size:12.0];
UIFont* customFont5 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Italic" size:12.0];
UIFont* customFont6 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Condensed" size:12.0];
```

I would like to know which `UIFont`'s are system. I practically need a method that would return a `BOOL` `YES` for variables: systemFont1, systemFont2, systemFont3 and `NO` for `customFont4`, `customFont5`, `customFont6`.

Since **Helvetica Neue** is system font on iOS7, this is subject of a debate, whether it should return `NO` or `YES` in these cases, but for my issue, it would be fine either way.

So my question is:

**How to verify if UIFont instance was created by either of system font methods?**

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is your method you want:

```
-(BOOL)isSystemFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    return ([[font familyName] isEqualToString:[[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f] familyName]])?YES:NO;
}
```

Or as an extension in Swift3

```
extension UIFont {
    func isSystemFont() -> Bool {
        return self.familyName == UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0).familyName
    }
}
```

Above method will return as you need

```
if([self isSystemFont:systemFont1]) NSLog(@"SystemFont");
else NSLog(@"Custom Font");
if([self isSystemFont:customFont1]) NSLog(@"SystemFont");
else NSLog(@"Custom Font");
```

Output is

```
2014-03-04 15:48:18.791 TestProject[4031:70b] SystemFont
2014-03-04 15:48:18.791 TestProject[4031:70b] Custom Font
```

Comment: And for Bold and Italic options? Considering it only compares the family name it should work...

Comment: Yes, as it's check its family so for `systemFont`, `boldSystemFont` and `italicSystemFont` above method will return YES.

Comment: Which class should this be implemented upon?

Comment: I implemented this as a category on UIFont.

Comment: @Legoless Then it's very confusing that it takes an argument. Also, what's the `? YES : NO` nonsense?

Comment: Obviously, I did not copy paste this method. ? is just ternary operator, I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, leagoless told that he use it as a category on UIFont. It would something like that `[systemFont1 isSystemFont]` so what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Legoless The use of the conditional operator is nonsense. Also, the method's declaration does not make any sense because it's obviously implemented on an unrelated class. Of course, I don't see what you did in your project. I'm talking about the code posted by TapasPal.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I haven't told that just copy and pate my answer. I just give you the idea. I don't find any wrong here.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe if you really thing that my answer is too bad to accept so I am requesting you to post a new answer. Cause the answer you have already posted is not working in IOS6 and earlier. It got crashed.

Comment: Take it easy guys. The idea you gave is fine, therefore I accepted the answer. I know my way around Obj-C. ;) But please explain why is the conditional operator nonsense here.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts consist of more than name and size. Here's a more thorough check. Caveat: only work on iOS 7.

```
BOOL FontIsEqualToFont(UIFont *font1, UIFont *font2)
{
    return [[[font1 fontDescriptor] fontAttributes] isEqual:[[font2 fontDescriptor] fontAttributes]];
}

// use as follows:
BOOL isSystemFont = FontIsEqualToFont(systemFont1, customFont1);
```

Another good way to uniquely identify fonts is to use their postscript names:

```
BOOL fontsAreEqual = [[[font1 fontDescriptor] postScriptName] isEqualToString:[[font2 fontDescriptor] postScriptName]];
```

Comment: First of all this method got crashed in IOS 6 and earlier. Secondly @Legoless want to find out the difference between systemFont & customFont. But as you used `fontDescriptor` so for `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]` and `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]` it'll return false which is not needed here.

Comment: @Legoless just want to know is the used font is systemFont or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just check fontName and/or familyName?

```
NSLog(@"Fontname: %@", systemFont1.fontName);
NSLog(@"Familyname: %@", systemFont1.familyName);
```

Comment: This only tells me the fontName. Which is different on iOS 6 and iOS 7. I'm guessing I could hardcode those, but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I have created method and tested in both **iOS 6** and **iOS7**. It is working fine. I was getting result what you are expected.

Here is Code:

```
- (BOOL)isSystemFont:(UIFont*)pFont {
    NSLog(@"pFont-%@",pFont.familyName);

    // Object created for comparing system font with custom font
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    NSLog(@"Font-%@",font.familyName);

    if ([pFont.familyName isEqualToString:font.familyName]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Hope, It will may helpful to you.

Comment: What would be the performance of this method, since you are creating a new instance of the font every time?

Comment: Good question. If you do not want to create instance everytime, you can declare instance in .h file and declare in viewDidLoad function. You can then use the instance in above function.